Anyone able to compile plotjuggler-CAN-dbs on windows10?
I am having a hard time compiling https://github.com/PlotJuggler/plotjuggler-CAN-dbs plugin for plotjugler.
I hawe MinGW and MSVS 2022. In MSVS2022 it stops on /bigobj error.
But what I really would like to do is get CMAKE to make a makefile for GCC or other type of compiler if possible as I would like not be dependent on MS tools.
Anyone else done this?
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/facontidavide/PlotJuggler.git
cd PlotJuggler/plotjuggler_plugins
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/PlotJuggler/plotjuggler-CAN-dbs.git
# Add the following line in the CMakeList.txt of the PlotJuggler, just after other plugin include lines
# add_subdirectory( plotjuggler_plugins/plotjuggler-CAN-dbs )
cd ../; mkdir build; cd build # Create a build folder in the root of PlotJuggler
cmake ..
make -j
sudo make install # In this approach, system-wide install is optional, you can diretly use the PJ inside the bin with CAN plugins included

